# How to remove an array element in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

```
productos: [
  {
    name: element 1
    number: 3167518236
    email: "example@gmail.com"
  }
  {
    name: element 2
    number: 3167518236
    email: "example@gmail.com"
  }
{
    name: element 3
    number: 3167518236
    email: "example@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

How can I for example remove the array two where name: element2 number: 3167518239 and email: example@gmail.com

I'm using this but it doesn't work!

```
db.list.update({},{"$unset":{productos:{name:"element 2"}}})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065314/remove-a-subdocument-nested-in-an-array-in-mongodb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823198/removing-a-subdocument-from-array-in-mongoddb

Answer (score 3):

Removing an element from an array in mongodb is done using [the `$pull` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

For your particular case, you can use `{name:"element 2"}` as the query inside the pull specification.

Comment: db.usuarios.update({},{"$pull":{productos:{nombre:"element 2"}}}) still not working!